# cosine negative power in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the inverse cosine for a value in R.

```
> cos^-1(x)
```

But

```
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

appears. Any suggestion?

Comment: That will fail in any programming language I know of.  Be very cautious when trying to translate written mathematical notation into computer code.

Comment: Not really a programming language, but Wolfram's Alpha at least understands it: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%5E-1%28x%29&dataset=

Comment: @PaulHiemstra sorry to disturb you. But I want to obtain cos^-1(-tan(35)*tan(21))=106 degree. While acos(cos(-tan(35)* tan( 21 )))=0.72. Where is my mistake plz?

Comment: The cos function works in radians, not degrees, where 360 degrees is 2pi radians.

Comment: I extended my answer a bit to include using degrees in these functions.

Comment: @ PaulHiemstra I appreciate your help and your taking the time to guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Inverse cosine function is called `acos`:

```
> cos(pi)
[1] -1
> acos(cos(pi))
[1] 3.141593
> all.equal(pi, acos(cos(pi)))
TRUE
```

**Note**: The trigonometric functions in R use radians, not degrees, e.g. 360 degrees is 2pi radians. Converting from and to radians:

```
deg2rad = function(deg) {
   return((pi * deg) / 180)
 }

rad2deg = function(rad) {
   return((180 * rad) / pi)
 }
```

You could use these functions, alternatively the `aspace` package provides these conversion functions (`as_radians`), and versions of `cos` and such which use degrees, e.g. `cos_d`.